# Region cannot be empty error with Terrain:FillRegion()?

Tags: roblox

I try this:

```
workspace.Terrain:FillRegion(Region3.new(Vector3.new(2048, -256, 2048), Vector3.new(-2048, -512, -2048)):ExpandToGrid(4), 4, Enum.Material.Basalt)
```

I get the error `Region cannot be empty`. What gives? Of course the region is empty, I am trying to change that. Is `:FillRegion()` broken?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has all the pieces for this to work properly, but you've defined your region inside out :

```
Region3.new(Vector3.new(2048, -256, 2048), Vector3.new(-2048, -512, -2048))
```

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Region3), `Region3.new()` expects that the first argument is the minimum value and the maximum second, and comes with the warning :

> Note that the order of the provided bounds matters: by switching them, the polarity of the Size components will switch. It is possible to create a Region3 with a negative volume.

Swapping these values in the constructor makes your code work just fine :

```
local resolution = 4
local max = Vector3.new(2048, -256, 2048)
local min = Vector3.new(-2048, -512, -2048)
local targetRegion = Region3.new(min, max)
local expandedRegion = targetRegion:ExpandToGrid(resolution)
workspace.Terrain:FillRegion(expandedRegion, resolution, Enum.Material.Basalt)
```